# Changing shape of a numpy array in a way that keeps the indices/positions of elements the same

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Suppose I have the following numpy array

```
[[[1 2 3]
  [4 5 6]
  [7 8 9]]

 [[1 2 3]
  [4 5 6]
  [7 8 9]]

 [[1 2 3]
  [4 5 6]
  [7 8 9]]]
```

I want to be able to resize this array (making it smaller or larger along an axis) but have existing elements have the same indices as they did before the resize.  So, if I decreased the size of axis 2 by one element, it would look like this:

```
[[[1 2]
  [4 5]
  [7 8]]

 [[1 2]
  [4 5]
  [7 8]]

 [[1 2]
  [4 5]
  [7 8]]]
```

And if I increased the size of axis 1, it would look like this:

```
[[[1 2 3]
  [4 5 6]
  [7 8 9]
  [0 0 0]]

 [[1 2 3]
  [4 5 6]
  [7 8 9]
  [0 0 0]]

 [[1 2 3]
  [4 5 6]
  [7 8 9]
  [0 0 0]]]
```

How would I do this, short of implementing all the loops and everything myself?

---

For reference, if I use the Numpy resize() function, and do `np.resize(my_array, (3, 3, 2))` to decrease the size of axis 2 from 3 to 2, Numpy simply changes the sizes of the dimensions and doesn't reorganize the array data itself, meaning that indices of elements are not preserved:

```
[[[1 2]
  [3 4]
  [5 6]]

 [[7 8]
  [9 1]
  [2 3]]

 [[4 5]
  [6 7]
  [8 9]]]
```

Comment: Looks like a concatenation job (or two) adding a new column and row.

Answer (score 0):

You can try defining a class that inherits from the `np.ndarray` class, defining an extra bound function that does the "resizing":

```
import numpy as np

class Array(np.ndarray):
    def __new__(cls, a, dtype=None, order=None):
        obj = np.asarray(a, dtype, order).view(cls)
        return obj
    
    def __array_wrap__(self, out_arr, context=None):
        return np.ndarray.__array_wrap__(self, out_arr, context)

    def resizing(self, cols):
        return self[..., :cols]

arr = np.tile(np.arange(1, 10), 3).reshape(3, 3, 3)
arr = Array(arr)
```

Now we can do:

```
print(arr.resizing(1))
```

Output:

```
[[[1]
  [4]
  [7]]

 [[1]
  [4]
  [7]]

 [[1]
  [4]
  [7]]]
```

```
print(arr.resizing(2))
```

Output:

```
[[[1 2]
  [4 5]
  [7 8]]

 [[1 2]
  [4 5]
  [7 8]]

 [[1 2]
  [4 5]
  [7 8]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't want `resize` or `reshape`

Make a sample array:

```
In [29]: arr = np.arange(1,10).reshape(1,3,3)
In [30]: arr
Out[30]: 
array([[[1, 2, 3],
        [4, 5, 6],
        [7, 8, 9]]])
```

To get your (3,3,3) array use `repeat`.  To keep the answer short, I'll stick with the (1,3,3):

```
In [31]: arr.repeat(3,0)
Out[31]: 
array([[[1, 2, 3],
        [4, 5, 6],
        [7, 8, 9]],

       [[1, 2, 3],
        [4, 5, 6],
        [7, 8, 9]],

       [[1, 2, 3],
        [4, 5, 6],
        [7, 8, 9]]])
```

Slicing can "cut off" a column

```
In [33]: arr[:,:,:2]
Out[33]: 
array([[[1, 2],
        [4, 5],
        [7, 8]]])
```

Adding on a row, use `concatenate`:

```
In [36]: np.concatenate((arr, np.zeros((1,1,3),int)), axis=1)
Out[36]: 
array([[[1, 2, 3],
        [4, 5, 6],
        [7, 8, 9],
        [0, 0, 0]]])
```

Keep in mind that `numpy` stores an array as `shape` and a 1d data-buffer.

```
In [40]: arr.ravel()
Out[40]: array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

`arr` is a `reshape` from `arange`.  Reshape preserves that 1d source.  So it isn't suitable for the kinds of changes you want.  `resize` works that 1d source also, though it can add on, or subtract from it.  Think in terms of making a new array with selected values from the original, rather than changing the array.

Answer (score 0):

I would use either `np.pad` or `np.zeros`.

1. using np.pad:

Build example array:

```
>>> import numpy as np               
>>> 
>>> A = np.resize(np.r_[1:10],(3,3,3))
>>> A
array([[[1, 2, 3],
        [4, 5, 6],
        [7, 8, 9]],

       [[1, 2, 3],
        [4, 5, 6],
        [7, 8, 9]],

       [[1, 2, 3],
        [4, 5, 6],
        [7, 8, 9]]])
```

Define the function

```
>>> def recut_pad(A,shp):
...     return np.pad(A[tuple(map(slice,shp))],[(0,max(0,sn-so)) for sn,so in zip(shp,A.shape)])
```

Try it out:

```
>>> recut_pad(A,(2,4,5))
array([[[1, 2, 3, 0, 0],
        [4, 5, 6, 0, 0],
        [7, 8, 9, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]],

       [[1, 2, 3, 0, 0],
        [4, 5, 6, 0, 0],
        [7, 8, 9, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]])
>>> recut_pad(A,(4,2,2))
array([[[1, 2],
        [4, 5]],

       [[1, 2],
        [4, 5]],

       [[1, 2],
        [4, 5]],

       [[0, 0],
        [0, 0]]])
```

2. Using `np.zeros` and slicing:

Define the function:

```
>>> def recut_zeros(A,shp):                                           
...     out = np.zeros(shp,A.dtype)                              
...     out[tuple(map(slice,A.shape))] = A[tuple(map(slice,shp))]
...     return out
```

Verify:

```
>>> np.all(recut_pad(A,(1,5,4))==recut_zeros(A,(1,5,4)))
True
>>> np.all(recut_pad(A,(7,2,3))==recut_zeros(A,(7,2,3)))
True
```